# How to show only the new element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am try to modification in this repo (https://github.com/particle-clicker/particle-clicker/) related to this http://particle-clicker.web.cern.ch/

I have add a new  item in the statistics that should show which last discovery have been opened by the player

For example in the start it shows this

Last Discovery: CP violation discovery! ,

And after some clicks ,

Last Discovery: CP violation discovery! , J/ψ discovery! ,

I only want to show  J/ψ discovery! not the CP violation discovery! , so It only show the latest element and remove/delete the previous one

Is there a way to do this?

```
 <li   class="list-group-item"> <p>Last Discovery: <span ng-repeat="a in achievements | orderBy:'state.timeAchieved' |  filter: { targetProperty: 'level' ,  threshold : 1 } " ng-show="a.isAchieved() ">             {{a.description}} {{$last ? '' : ($index==a.length-2) ? ' and ' : ', '}}  </span></p> </li> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this in js like this

```js
document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = "the value of the last discover"
```

```html
<p>Last Discovery: <span id="spanId"></span></p>
```

And you need to run this js code in the line where this project select the last discover